# Privileged helper doesn't get notarized in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, notarization

so after struggling with privileged helpers for over three weeks I finally got my app working. I needed a helper to send some root shell commands and everything works just as expected. However, whenever I try to notarize the app, the helper tool doesn't work, and when I export the archive without notarizing it, it works as expected. But I want to notarize it because that was the whole point to get a privileged helper up and running.

Some info:

1. If I notarize it, the program doesn't work as expected
2. If I export an archive (by choosing directly distribute to customers options ) but don't notarize it, then it doesn't work either
3. If I export a pure archive of the app, it works. But when I tested it on a friend's Mac, they had to go to System Preferences to manually allow the app to run since it wasn't notarized.

Someone suggested that it's an entitlements issue; that I need to add an entitlements file to the helper tool rather than the main app. Does anyone know how that can be done? If so, what sort of entitlement would I need to add?

PS: The notarization process required enabling hardened runtime and without that, I cannot notarize it.

Comment: Is your privileged helper pre-compiled? Where is it stored in your project?